# crawler vs scraper

Tags: web-crawler, terminology, scraper

Can somebody distinguish between a crawler and scraper in terms of scope and functionality.

Comment: Those terms do not have precise definitions. Do you have usage examples?

Comment: I want to write an application that walks over a web site based on some xpath based rules (follow specific hyperlinks) and then extract data from some leaf pages. So it includes both crawling and scraping. I need to find out best possible tools for both the steps.

Comment: Lots of platforms are perfectly good at downloading web pages and applying RegExp to extract links or scraped values.  Use what you know.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327392/crawling-vs-web-scraping

Answer (score 112, accepted):

A crawler gets web pages -- i.e., given a starting address (or set of starting addresses) and some conditions (e.g., how many links deep to go, types of files to ignore) it downloads whatever is linked to from the starting point(s).

A scraper takes pages that have been downloaded or, in a more general sense, data that's formatted for display, and (attempts to) extract data from those pages, so that it can (for example) be stored in a database and manipulated as desired.

Depending on how you use the result, scraping may well violate the rights of the owner of the information and/or user agreements about use of web sites (crawling violates the latter in some cases as well). Many sites include a file named [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) in their root (i.e. having the URL `http://server/robots.txt`) to specify how (and if) crawlers should treat that site -- in particular, it can list (partial) URLs that a crawler should not attempt to visit. These can be specified separately per crawler (user-agent) if desired.

Answer (score 6):

Crawlers surf the web, following links.  An example would be the Google robot that gets pages to index.  Scrapers extract values from forms, but don't necessarily have anything to do with the web.

Comment: Scrapers extract values from HTML, not necessarily forms.

Comment: Scrapers extract value from screens, not necessarily HTML.  For example, I once used a scraper to extract values from old mainframe forms.

Comment: I can't give Google a free pass on this. Google is a crawler, yes, but ALSO a scraper. How else do they have the meta description to display in the search results? the title? the dates of posts? They're the ultimate crawler AND scraper.

Answer (score 5):

Web crawler gets links (Urls - Pages) in a logic and **scraper** get values (extracting) from HTML.

There are so many web crawler tools. [Visit page](http://cuneytyesilkaya.blogspot.com/2012/01/web-crawler-tools.html) to see some. Any XML - HTML parser can used to extract (**scrape**) data from crawled pages. (I recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for parsing and extracting data)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, crawlers would follow the links to reach numerous pages while scrapers is, in some sense, just pulling the contents displayed online and would not reach the deeper links.

The most typical crawler is google bots, which would follow the links to reach all the web pages on your website and would index the contents if they found it useful(that's why you need robots.txt to tell which contents you do not want to be indexed). So we could search such kind of contents on its website. While the purpose of scrapers is just to pull the contents for personal uses and would not have much effects on others.

However, there's no distinct difference about crawlers and scrapers now as some automated web scraping tools also allow you to crawl the website by following the links, like Octoparse and import.io. They are not the crawlers like google bots, but they are able to automatically crawl the websites to get numerous data without coding.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapers and crawlers do not always distinguish, I mean - you can find crawlers which scrape, in fact, [Scraper Crawler](https://www.scrapercrawler.com) is doing both and is named accordingly:

- it crawls to a URL i.e. indexes all the URL in that main URL
- depth of crawling is how far the indexing goes in the URL tree
- then it scrapes whatever you define in a regexp

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I'll respond anyway for the newcomer that will wonder here.

From what I can gather and understand it seems that those two terms are often confused with each other due to their similarity and people will often refer to them as the same thing.

However, they are not quite the same. A crawler(or spider) will follow each link in the page it crawls from the starter page. This is why it is also referred to as a spider bot since it will create a kind of a spider web of pages.

A scraper will extract the data from a page, usually from the pages downloaded with the crawler.

If you are interested in either of those, you can try the [Norconex HTTP Collector](https://opensource.norconex.com/collectors/http/).